# Invalid Tumblr HTML markup: Stray start tag html

Tags: html, validation, tumblr, w3c-validation

I validate my tumblog from time to time, to solve mistakes. Most of these errors and warnings are explainable but I don't understand this one.

What does that mean? (note: I have no control over the outputted markup)

**Error:**

```
Error: Stray start tag html.
From line 3, column 1; to line 3, column 14
</script>
<html lang=en>
<head
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>var __pbpa = true;</script><script>var translated_warning_string = 'Warnung: Gib dein Tumblr-Passwort nur dann ein, wenn du \u201chttps://www.tumblr.com/login\u201d\x0ain der Adresszeile deines Browsers siehst.\x0a\x0aAu\u00dferdem sollte dort ein gr\u00fcnes \u201cTumblr, Inc.\u201d-Logo zu sehen sein.\x0a\x0aSpammer und andere Strolche benutzen gef\u00e4lschte Formulare, um an Passw\u00f6rter zu kommen.\x0a\x0aTumblr wird dich niemals bitten, dich vom Blog eines Users aus einzuloggen.\x0a\x0aWillst du ganz sicher fortfahren?';</script><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://assets.tumblr.com/assets/scripts/pre_tumblelog.js?_v=9a8f53878980f315a039f29ddc0b2038"></script>
<html lang="en">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start tags for the HTML and HEAD elements are optional.

A SCRIPT element may not appear outside the HEAD or BODY.

Since you have a SCRIPT immediately after the Doctype, you *implicitly* open the HTML and HEAD elements.

Move the `<script>` so it appears after your `<head>` tag.

Comment: The `<script>` tag can't be moved, it's automatically inserted by Tumblr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349731/invalid-tumblr-head-duplicated-doctype-strange-javascript?rq=1