# invalid tumblr head, duplicated doctype, strange javascript

Tags: javascript, tumblr

i got a problem with my tumblr blogs. There is some piece of javascript and a duplicated doctype in my two different themes, which i can't remove on the custom settings area or on the theme markup settings.

The support couldn't help.

The really bad thing on this: the page is damn invalid, so you can't visit it in some browser, especially on Linux.

The wrong code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><script>!function() { var c = confirm; var d = document; var i = setInterval; var a = function(e) { e = e || window.event; var t = e.target || e.srcElement; if (t.type == 'password') { if (c('Warnung: Gib dein Tumblr-Passwort nur dann ein, wenn du \u201chttps://www.tumblr.com/login\u201d\x0ain der Adresszeile deines Browsers siehst.\x0a\x0aAu\u00dferdem sollte dort ein gr\u00fcnes \u201cTumblr, Inc.\u201d-Logo zu sehen sein.\x0a\x0aSpammer und andere Strolche benutzen gef\u00e4lschte Formulare, um an Passw\u00f6rter zu kommen.\x0a\x0aTumblr wird dich niemals bitten, dich vom Blog eines Users aus einzuloggen.\x0a\x0aWillst du ganz sicher fortfahren?')) { a = function() {}; } else { t.value = ""; return false; } } }; i(function() { if (typeof d.addEventListener != 'undefined') d.addEventListener('keypress', a, false)}, 0); }();</script><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*All* Tumblr blogs have this problem. Even the [official Tumblr staff blog](http://staff.tumblr.com/):

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <script>
>   !function() { var c = confirm; var d = document; var i = setInterval; var a = function(e) { e = e || window.event; var t = e.target || e.srcElement; if (t.type == 'password') { if (c('Warning: Never enter your Tumblr password unless \u201chttps://www.tumblr.com/login\u201d\x0ais the address in your web browser.\x0a\x0aYou should also see a green \u201cTumblr, Inc.\u201d identification in the address bar.\x0a\x0aSpammers and other bad guys use fake forms to steal passwords.\x0a\x0aTumblr will never ask you to log in from a user\u2019s blog.\x0a\x0aAre you absolutely sure you want to continue?')) { a = function() {}; } else { t.value = ""; return false; } } }; i(function() { if (typeof d.addEventListener != 'undefined') d.addEventListener('keypress', a, false)}, 0); }();
> </script>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <!-- NOTE: This theme is used multiple places. Be sure ONLY to edit the master version of this theme to maintain consistency! -->
> <html>
> ```
>
> …

Tumblr seems to inject this script into all blog pages, probably to prevent/warn users not to enter their password into password fields under the blog owner's control.

As long as Tumblr injects a DOCTYPE automatically, you could remove the DOCTYPE from your custom theme. Nevertheless, the injected `script` element will still be *before* the opening `html` element, resulting in invalid markup.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue, and facebook was failing to share the url,  so we work around it by removing the `DOCTYPE` from the `tumblr` template in order to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr automatically puts a doctype and a couple of scripts above each page. The scripts warn users when they try to type in password fields on the blog and do some data tracking through AJAX and transparent pixels.

According to the HTML syntax definition, certain tags can be omitted from an HTML document when the beginning and end of the elements can be implied. [Read this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) for the full details. The important thing is that you don't need to open (or close) the html and head elements. So tumblr doesn't actually do something wrong by putting the doctype followed by a script. What's wrong is that the default themes and documentation doesn't specify that we shouldn't open these tags.

Knowing all this, we can make our tumblr sites valid by not opening the html and head in our themes. HOWEVER, tumblr automatically appends additional code at the end of the head, and it will break the page if you actually don't put the head tags.

Tumblr also puts a bunch of invalid attributes, duplicate meta tags and is overal quite messy. There's no way to make a tumblr site valid HTML at all, which is quite horrible.