# Can't get webpage title to look centered on all browsers

Tags: html, css, tumblr

this is my newly developed webpage - http://hellbikeo.tumblr.com/ and i can't get the title right.

It looks the way it should on Firefox and on IE.

It doesn't looks right on Chrome and Opera. If You click "Inscpet element" on the header - You will see that highlighted area has different position than the title itself. (the highlighted area is correct).

Because of that i can't make my title look right - because when it's centered on IE and Firefox, it's not centered on Chrome and Opera. I tried playing with margins etc. but I'm learning html/css for just 3 days and right now it seems hopeless to me.

What can i do?

Comment: can you post some code and show what you have tried? Links to sites often change or dry up over time...

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on the latest Firefox and Chrome. Are you using the latest versions of the browsers you mentioned?

Comment: (...) Yes, i have the newest version and on my PC, webpage title on Chrome is little lower than on on firefox. How is that even possible?

Comment: Looks fine in my browsers.

Comment: Have you edited it recently? The title is currently centered.

Comment: You have a couple of serious errors in your source, such as the `script` on top, before the `html` start tag. Avoid situations like that. And your page ends with `</`

Comment: @MrLister the `script` before the `html` is an unfortunate hazard of Tumblr. I've written support about it before, but received no response.

Comment: @Ally: Even if the support would have answered, they [don’t seem to know anything about it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15349731/1591669).