# Facebook Object Debugger returns 404 not found when trying to scrape

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a simple **Tumblr** website blog, upon which I post content.

However since I changed my DNS, the Facebook Object debugger sees really old data for my root url: http://www.kofferbaque.nl/ and for every post (for instance: http://kofferbaque.nl/post/96638253942/moodoid-le-monde-moo) it shows a `404 not found`, which is bullshit because the actual content is there.

The full error message: `Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.`

I have tried the following things to fix it:

- clear browser cache / cookies / history
- using `?fbrefresh=1` after the URL (didn't work)
- I've added a FB app_id to the page (made sure the app was in production - added the correct namespaces etc. - also didn't change anything)
- Checked out other questions regarding this subject
- Rechecked all my meta tags a dozen times

What other options are there to fix this issue? 
If you need more info please ask in the comments.

**2014-09-08 - Update**

When throwing my url into the static debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://www.kofferbaque.nl/. The 'net' tab from firebug gives the following response:

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kofferbaque.nl%2F&amp;_fb_noscript=1" /><meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="DENY" />
```

**2014-09-11 - Update**

- removed duplicate `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration
- cleanup up `<html>` start tag (aka - removed IE support temporarily)

I've placed a test blog post to see if it would work, it didn't. Somehow my root url started 'magically' updating itself. Or let's say, it removed the old data - probably due to the fact that I removed the old app it was still refering to. However, it still doesn't see the 'newer' tags correctly.

Still no succes

**2014-09-12 - Update**

Done:

- moving `<meta>` tags to the top of the `<head>` element
- removed `fb:app_id` from page + the body script, for it has no purpose.

This appearantly doesn't make any changes. It also appears that tumblr injects lots of script tags at the start of the head element. Maybe that is the reason the Facebook scraper doesn't 'see' the meta tags.

The frustrating bit is that through some other og tag scanner: http://iframely.com/debug?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fkofferbaque.nl%2F, it shows all the correct info.

Comment: I deleted my "not-really-helpful" answer, but if FB gets 404, than probably it's something regarding your server (Apache/nginx) configuration. Try logging the request that Facebook sends (all data, headers etc) and study what could be the reason that your server returns "not found". 404 is a http response code, so it has nothing to do with the DNS - the request actually got to the server.

Comment: Can you remove script tag before html.It will help us to debug.

Comment: @Gerard Westerhof Your home page is working for me.Can you please post your rewrite rule & make sure your are not blocking facebook crawler

Comment: I'm not in command of the rewrite rule. Since the domain is just pointing to a 'tumblr' website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook can't scrape meta data after I've moved Wordpress to new server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220600/facebook-cant-scrape-meta-data-after-ive-moved-wordpress-to-new-server)

Answer (score 1):

First, the HTML is not valid. You got the doctype two times (at least on the post page), and there is content before the html tag (script tag and IE conditionals).

This may be the problem, but make sure you put the og-tags together at the beginning of the head section - The debugger only reads part of the page afaik, so make sure the og-tags are in that part. Put all the other og-tags right after "og:site_name".

Btw: `?fbrefresh=1` is not really necessary, you can use ANY parameter - just to create a different url. But the debugger offers a button to refresh the scraping, so it´s useless anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have made some changes to the HTML. But the scraper must re-visit my page I guess.

Comment: <script>var __pbpa = true;</script><script>var translated_warning_string = 'Waarschuwing: voer........

Comment: I know. The problem is dicussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349731/invalid-tumblr-head-duplicated-doctype-strange-javascript

Comment: "We have the same issue, and facebook was failing to share the url" - exactly, makes sense as it is invalide html. not sure how to get rid of it though. tumblr is a pretty closed system, right?

Comment: It shouldn't even matter becuse facebook shared the url before I pointed my domain to the tumblr blog. I assume that the `script` tag was there aswell.