# Always getting "Invalid theme HTML" when submitting a theme on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

Is anyone else having trouble submitting themes to Tumblr? I have had this problem for two weeks now.

Whatever I try in the "Source code" field here https://www.tumblr.com/themes/new comes back as "Invalid theme HTML".

I have even tried the example markup here https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes and that still returns as "Invalid theme HTML".

Is there something wrong with the service at the moment? Do I need to use a particular combination of browser / OS?! I have tried with Chrome and IE11 on Windows.

I have contacted Support and they have replied asking me to send them a screenshot.

Comment: I always had this error, but after confirm my email address, it seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all kinds of things that didn't work.  But it so happened that I'd just changed my email address and needed to verify it.  Once I clicked the verification link, the invalid theme HTML error went away.

So I suppose if you see this error, it might be as bizarre and unrelated as that.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you encounter an issue like this:

1. remove parts of the page until the uploader accepts it

When it finally accepts it:

2. try to add back half of the part you just removed, until you pinpoint exactly what's wrong
3. resolve/remove the invalid part
4. add back the rest of the parts you removed.

If it doesn't accept anymore:

5. go to step 1 and repeat until the problematic parts are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your theme contains the following tags:

```
<html>
<body>
{rss}
{favicon}
{customcss}
{metadescription}
{photoalt}
```

I had the same problem as I was missing `{CustomCSS}`

Answer (score 0):

There’s a number of things that can cause your theme to get rejected, and
unfortunately there’s no error message other than “you messed *something* up”
so it’s not always easy to figure out the error.

Here’s some things to try:

1. The doctype has to be `<!DOCTYPE html>`, even though Tumblr [always inserts a doctype anyways.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5642982/5719760)
2. Your theme *must* have `html`, `head`, and `body` tags, even though they’re [usually optional.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15370314/5719760) Tumblr uses `</head>` to place the OpenGraph / Twitter card meta tags, for one.
3. Check that you have the variables listed in [MachineElf’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35870593/5719760) (expanded here into how you’d actually use them because just putting e.g. `{RSS}` in your theme bare would be invalid).

Example HTML including these things:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
{block:Description}
    <meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}">
{/block:Description}
<style>
    {CustomCSS}
</style>
</head>
<body>
{block:Posts}
    {block:Photo}
        <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">
    {/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}
</body>
</html>
```